# Reference a marker with an id

Tags: javascript, dictionary, reference, click, google-maps-markers

I have an array of element that are showed on the map with markers. I want to set some property when i click a button contained in a popup on the marker, but when i do that, it apply the proprerty to every marker. So, is possible to give a marker an id so i can get a reference and set the property to only THAT marker and not all?
By the way, I'm coding in javascript.
I've declared the markers like that (stazioni is the array that contains items with id, text and coordinates)
Sorry for the bad english, also i'm new here. Thank you in advance.

```
stazioni.map(item => {
                var marker = new L.marker(item.coordinates, {icon: greenMarker})
                    .bindPopup(item.text + '<hr>' + setContent + popupContent + "Disponibile!")
                    .openPopup();
                marker.addTo(map);
                marker.on('click', function(e) {
                    map.flyTo(e.latlng, 15);
                    marker.setIcon(yellowMarker); 
                });
});
```